# How to query for any match in an array using Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a questions array that can have yes/no values for multiple items as well as one boolean that can return true/false.

The query should return the array data something similar to this:

```
"QUESTIONS": [
{
   "ONE_IND": "Y or N",
   "TWO_IND": "Y or N",
   "THREE_IND": "Y or N",
   "FOUR_IND": "Y or N",
   "FIVE_IND": "Y or N",
   "SIX_IND": "Y or N",
   "BOOLEAN_IND": true or false
}
```

I also have some other term filters, but the part I need is how to query the array specifically so that I can match at least one value.  Really what I'm looking for might be what I would use in java to see if the array isn't empty, as in:

```
if(array.length > 0) {
   //Then do something here.
};
```

What I'm trying is something like this, but it's not working to return anything:

```
GET test_<name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "VALUE",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.ANOTHER_IND": "Y"
              }
            },
             {
              "match": {
                "VALUE.MY_QUESTIONS_ARRAY" : "SOME_VALUE"
              }  
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.YET_ANOTHER_IND": "Y"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Comment: can you post your mappings?

Comment: No, it's proprietary code.  I'm just using some similar type code for illustration purposes ,but suffice to say I only have yes/no values (strings for the json) and one true/false (boolean in the json).

Comment: What is VALUE? Is QUESTIONS a nested type? Your example is not very clear. Can you cook up a simple mapping that works with the example you've mentioned? That should help us understand your question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had tried to use the "exists" filter for this, but I got this working first with missing and then using not missing.

The code for missing is:

```
GET <path>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "VALUE",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.ONE_IND": "Y"
              }
            },
            {
              "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                  "missing": {
                    "field": "VALUE.MY_QUESTIONS_ARRAY"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.TWO_IND": "N"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.THREE_IND": "Y"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and the code for not missing is, which is really what I wanted to get:

```
GET <path>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "VALUE",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.ONE_IND": "Y"
              }
            },
            {
              "filtered": {
                "filter": {
                  "not": {
                    "filter": {
                      "missing": {
                        "field": "VALUE.MY_QUESTIONS_ARRAY"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.TWO_IND": "N"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "VALUE.THREE_IND": "Y"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This way I am basically searching for an array that is not empty.  There may be other ways to do this, but it works and I'm posting it so someone else may find it useful.